# R - Ratio of a dichotomus variable per ZIP code, grouped by ZIP code into a new df

Tags: r

I'm new to R and running a bit into trouble.

I have a data frame with subjects of a city, the ZIP-Code they individually live in and their outcome (0, 1).

```
id <- 1:5000
zip <- sample(100:200, 5000, replace = TRUE)
outcome <- rbinom(5000, 1, 0.23)
df <- data.frame(id, outcome, zip)

abs <- table(df$zip, df$outcome)
ratio <- round(prop.table(abs, 1), 2)
```

With "abs" I get the absolute numbers of each outcome per outcome and ZIP-code.

With "ratio" I get the percentage for each outcome per ZIP-Code, and the sum of both outcome-columns would be 1.

My questions are, A: How do I only get the percentage for one of the outcomes into a table per ZIP-code,

and B: How can I create a data frame grouped only as the ZIP-codes with one ratio of the outcome created in the table before (or directly). 100 rows of the ZIP-codes and only one ratio per ZIP-code.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the first few rows of your expected output?

Comment: @harro-cyranka Thank you for your attention. Basically I want "ratio" and just the "1" column in a new data frame. Scratch the "0" column. I want this to be the base for my shape-file map. Then the colour would be the outcome ratio. Like: ZIP-code 125, ratio 0,47.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer using tidyverse. Basically, we can group observations by zip and then summarize by taking the mean. Since the only possible outcomes are 0 and 1, the mean gives us the proportion of 1s.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1) ##I set a seed, just to ensure reproducibility 
id <- 1:5000
zip <- sample(100:200, 5000, replace = TRUE)
outcome <- rbinom(5000, 1, 0.23)
df <- data.frame(id, outcome, zip) %>% as_tibble()


new_df <- df %>% group_by(zip) %>% summarise(ratio = mean(outcome))
new_df
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works with my real df like a charm.